# Adding non-advertised shortcuts to Visual Studio deployment project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, deployment

I would like to create two shortcuts to my application during setup. The application is deployed as a Visual Studio 2008 deployment project.

The shortcuts would basically point to the same executable, however I would like one to be advertised (i.e., checking if the installed files are the same as the files packaged by the original installer), and one to be non-advertised (just a regular link pointing to the executable).

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks,

kreb

Comment: No, sorry, I had to give up the advertised shortcut and just use a regular shortcut instead.. :(